Designating list nesting via parameter
I am trying to make a simple set of nested lists, but intentionally trying to reduce visual clutter to the code by limiting bracket use and environments. I want to create something like this:
\Argument {IIa} {Main argument}
\Logic {Main argument contains ...}
\Argument {IIIa} {Subargument}
\Logic {blah blah blah}
\Argument {IIIIa} {Subargument}
\Logic {blah blah blah}
\Argument {IIIIb} {Subargument}
\Logic {blah blah blah}
\Argument {IIIIc} {Subargument}
\Logic {blah blah blah}
\Argument {IIIb} {Subargument}
\Logic {blah blah blah}
... where the custom command \Argument has as it's first parameter a nesting level, which is used to guide the rest of the input into a nested series of enumerates, like so:

IIa. Main argument
Main argument contains ...

IIIa. Subargument
blah blah blah

IIIIa. Subargument
blah blah blah
IIIIb. Subargument
blah blah blah
IIIIc. Subargument
blah blah blah


IIIb. Subargument
blah blah blah



I have tried several approaches, but none that do away with the need for an explicit scope for the nesting levels. How can I create the nesting by definition, via the first argument in the \Argument function?
